# How to connect a server that run wso2 API manager to show statics on a server that run wso2 analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

How to connect a server that run wso2 API manager to show statics on a server that run wso2 analytics that actually exist on differnt servers with different IP.
I am using version 3.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the documentation and configure analytics for APIM 3.2.0.

In the configurations, instead of using `localhost`, use the IP address of the analytics server.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#configuring-apim-analytics

Comment: Hi sir. Iface many problems .can u tell me pls which parts of api manager deployment.toml and in analytics server which parts must be change (worker and dashboeard)

Comment: You first have to get the analytics worker up and running. You don't need to point to API Manager from the analytics side. Once it is up, point to the analytics host from API Manager configurations. There are specific configurations mentioned in the documentation with `[[apim.analytics.url_group]]`. If you only have one analytics instance, add the configurations as below.   


`[apim.analytics]`       
`enable = true`  

`[[apim.analytics.url_group]]`   
`analytics_url =["tcp://analytics_host:7611"]`  
`analytics_auth_url =["ssl://analytics_host:7711"]`

Comment: thanx so much . exactly I have one one analytics instance what about the analytics worker and dashboard conf ?

Comment: Since they are local to each other, you don't need to change anything

Comment: In analytics_auth_url conf part when I run api manager I recieve an error that tell connection refused .what is the possible reason ?

Comment: hi buddy I have 2 servers .they dont run locally. what about this configuration ?(analytics side configre)